# How to succinctly express that something may or may not happen, but if it does, then <X>?

Tags: phrases

The only ways I can think of are *if and when* or *until such time*.  Both seem inelegant.

Examples:

- If and when you see Phil, tell him I said hi.
- If or when you see Phil, tell him I said hi.

or

- Until such time as you need the money, put it in your savings account.

In the last example (until such time) I want to express that it may not happen.

Comment: *If* ABC happens, then X. *Should* ABC happen, then X.

Comment: ... Yes; 'if' here pragmatically entails 'at the time when, or as soon as possible'. 'If you see Phil, would you tell him ...'. And 'Put the money in your savings account until you need it' doesn't demand that 'you' ever will, in common usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether there is anything 'inelegant' about *if and when* is a matter of taste. Those who dislike it probably do so because it reminds them of the overly pedantic way of writing that is typical of legal documents. But the remedy for that is simple: if what is one is writing is not a legal document, one can simply use **either** *if* or *when*; one usually doesn't need both.

*When* logically implies *if*. If somebody instructs me 'When you see Phil, tell him I said "hi"' that means that I should wait until I see Phil, and then act accordingly. If I never see Phil, the occasion will not arise for telling him that. By following the instruction 'When you see Phil . . .' I will at the same time be following the possible instruction 'If you see Phil . . .'; it is thus not necessary to make the latter explicit. Of course, as a matter of pragmatics, *when* is likely to be used only if there is an expectation that I will actually see Phil.

*If* doesn't logically imply *when*, but, as has already been suggested in the comments, in most real-life contexts, it is likely to be treated as if it did. Suppose that somebody tells me 'If you see Phil, tell him I said "hi"'. When should I tell him you said 'hi'? The literal meaning does not say anything about the timing, but clearly I should not do that before I see him, because at that point I cannot be sure that I will see him. Moreover how would I go about telling him that before seeing him? It is also difficult to see how and why I would tell him that some time after seeing him. So obviously the only reasonable time to do it is when I see him. *If* thus for most ends and purposes includes *when* in such contexts, even though it does not logically imply it.

It is only when a great deal is at stake, and one wants to eliminate the slightest possibility that one's words will be misinterpreted, that one needs to resort to *if and when*, and that is typically the case in legal documents.

Of course there are plenty of other ways of saying the same thing, such as 'Your seeing Phil is a sufficient condition of your telling him I said "hi"' or 'Your seeing Phil will trigger your obligation to tell him I said "hi"' but none of them is likely to be particularly succinct or elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If **Y** is the thing that may or may not happen, **X** is *contingent* on **Y**.

> Contingent = dependent on or conditioned by something else
>
> ”Payment is contingent on fulfillment of certain conditions”
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contingent)

Comment: That is certainly a possible way of expressing what the OP is asking about, but it is debatable whether it is more succinct or elegant that just saying 'if Y, then X'.

Comment: @jsw29 thanks for the discussion. I tried to find a complete sentence that covers the question rather than a quasi-mathematical construction. Also, the "If Y, then X" construct seems to imply "If Y, then necessarily X" and “if not Y, then necessarily not X” which is not quite what the question seeks ("may or may not...").  To say X is contingent on Y is not to say anything about the likelihood of Y, which is still something that “may or may not” happen, as specified by the question.

Comment: Just 'for the record', in logic 'if Y, then X' does not imply either of these, although it is true that, in everyday usage, it may be misunderstood that way.

Comment: I guess we have beaten all of that one into shape for the PO. Thanks. :)